# How do I get XCode 6 to generate a Release Application

Tags: macos, xcode6

How do I get XCode 6 to generate a Release Application.
 This was straightforward in XCode 3, and I thought I had figured this out in XCode 4.

I have created workspaces which generate a Release, but I cannot seem to get a simple project to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the build configuration to Debug or Release, choose 'Edit Scheme' from the 'Product' menu.

There you can select release/Debug from see Run->Build Configuration. If you want to Archive, you can do it from Product->Archive